# How To Get Subversion on Linux Status

Tags: linux

I have installed subversion using: apt-get install subversion

How would I detect if subversion is running from a script, i can detect it if its installed but how would I check its status and then act upon it?

Comment: By "its status", do you mean the exit code svn emits on the end of execution?

Comment: no whether it is currently running or not

Answer (score 0):

You can query this information from the process table, using [ps(1)](http://www.manpages.info/linux/ps.1.html). There are many ways to find out if a process with a certain name is in the process table. What follows is one way.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "`ps -ef|awk '$8 ~ /[:print:]*svnserve/ { print $2 }'`" ]; then
  # do things you should do when svn server daemon is not running
else
  # do things you should do when svn server daemon is running
fi
```

And here is another.

```
if [ -z "`ps -ef|grep "[s]vnserve"`" ];then
  # do things you should do when svn server daemon is not running
else
  # do things you should ddo when svn server daemon is running
fi
```